# short exact sequence from fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, exact-sequence, fibration

Let $G$ be a finite group acting freely on a path connected topological space $X$. The covering map $X \to X/G$ induces a long exact sequence of homotopy groups. Since $\pi_1(G) = 1$ and $\pi_0(X) = 0$, we obtain a short exact sequence
$$
1 \to \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(X/G) \to G \to 0.
$$
The last map here, call it $\partial$, is in principle only a map between pointed sets.

**Baby question:** Is $\partial$ always a group homomorphism?

**Question:** If $\partial$ is a group homomorphism, then the above is a short exact sequence of groups. Is it always non-split? (Assuming of course that $G, \pi_1(X) \neq 1$. I am most interested in the case when $\pi_1(X) = \mathbf{Z}$.)

Comment: If you have a closed curve at your basepoint, you lift it and the endpoint p of the lift is on the fiber of the basepoint: the image under \partial is the element of G that maps the basepoint of X to p. This is clearly a group morphism. In other words, this the map is the monodromy.

Comment: Why do you think it should always be non-split? If you drop finiteness and only require $G$ is discrete it is easy to came out with split examples (for instance $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $X$ an infinite cylinder so that $X/G=T^2$). Does finiteness play a a crucial role in your intuition?

Answer (score 1):

For your main question, covering space theory tells us that *every* short exact sequence of groups
$$1 \to N \to E \to G \to 1
$$
occurs in this fashion. So, pick your favorite non-split example with $G$ finite.

Here's a few more details. Pick a path connected CW-complex $Y$ such that $\pi_1(Y)$ is isomorphic to $E$. Covering space theory gives us the following:

- A regular covering map $f : X \mapsto Y$ such that $X$ is path connected, and such that the induced homomorphism $f_* : \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)\approx E$ is injective and has image $N$.
- An isomorphism between the quotient group $G \approx E/N$ and the deck transformation group of the covering map $f$, hence $Q$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on $S$ with quotient space $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=S^1\times S^\infty\to X/G=S^1\times\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ where $G=\mathbb Z/2$. Then the short exact sequence is $0\to\mathbb {Z}\to\mathbb {Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb Z/2\to 0$, which is split.